# Как определить какой ноде iscsi какой UUID/PARTUUID раздел принадлежит?

Tags: linux, сервер, unix

Доброго времени суток!

Такая ситуация, есть linux сервер, к нему по iscsi с двух разных сетевых хранилищ подключены 6 нод, на каждой по одному разделу одинакового размера. Нужно определить какой раздел на какой ноде расположен.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/` ?

Comment: Да именно так! Вчера получилось, товарищ подсказал!